# Looking for books on the typological descriptions of language families

Tags: linguistic-typology

I've recently stumbled upon "The Cambridge Handbook of Linguistic Typology". The book is absolutely amazing. It contains short (about 30-40 pages long) typological profiles of different language families; each covers all major topics like phonology, morphology and syntax, explains the key features of the family, compares the languages from the family etc. All very well written, and in the end you really understand what the family is and how its languages work. Basically, the best descriptions of language families one could possibly fit into 40 pages.

The only downside is: the book only covers like ten families.

I wonder if there are other similar books (or other resources) on this topic. Maybe some encyclopaedia of language families.

Comment: _The World's Major Languages_ gives good sketches of about 50 languages, including often the families they come from. But "major" means "high population", so lotsa language families are left out. For North American languages, the best is Lyle Campbell's _American Indian Languages_, which deals with them by family, generally giving most of the typological facts for each.

Answer (score 7):

Routledge has published a number of [language collections](https://www.routledge.com/Routledge-Language-Family-Series/book-series/SE0091) which may satisfy your interests, which covers 25 language groups (Uralic, Indo-Aryan, Semitic, Bantu...), where there may be general family overviews (chapters on general phonological properties in the family, morphology etc), and short structural summaries of particular languages. Some volumes have multiple editions with different content. One of the volumes is dedicated to language isolates, so it's not just about members of the big phylla.